# Como fazer um cast in Java?

Tags: java, cast

Esse modelo está funcionando, observem a figura!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode perceber que está concatenando duas variáveis String como podem ver na figura abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu problema agora é conseguir concatenar uma variável Integer com uma variável String, porque o eclipse não permite, como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu teria que fazer um **Cast**, porém estou tendo dificuldade de fazer por falta de experiência, preciso de ajuda nesse sentido!

Esse é o código;

```
/*lista de NaoConformidade*/
@Autorizacao(values = { AutorizacaoSistema.M_ADM })
public List<TipoInconsistenciaEntity> getListNaoConformidade() {
    AbstractCriteriaSearch<TipoInconsistenciaEntity> filtro =
            new AbstractCriteriaSearch<TipoInconsistenciaEntity>(new TipoInconsistenciaEntity());
    filtro.addOrder("codigo", ASC);
    List<TipoInconsistenciaEntity> lista = tipoInconsistenciaService.listarEntidades(filtro);
    List<TipoInconsistenciaEntity> listaRetorno = new ArrayList<TipoInconsistenciaEntity>();

    for (TipoInconsistenciaEntity pj : lista) {
        if(pj.getCodigo() > 5000) {
            TipoInconsistenciaEntity p = new TipoInconsistenciaEntity();
            p.setDescricao(pj.getDescricao());
            p.setCodigo(pj.getCodigo() + " - ["+ pj.getDescricao() + "]");

            listaRetorno.add(p);
        }
    }
    return listaRetorno;
}
```

Comment: Bom dia, cara.. você só pode receber um campo Integer ali, não tem como fazer um cast pois é uma descrição e contém caracteres não numéricos. Ou você altera o teu objeto e consequentemente seus getters and setters ou grava o código (o que faz mais sentido).

Comment: não tem como alterar o objeto porque eles estão sendo usando em outros lugares do projeto, se eu mudar o objeto vai ser consideravelmente desvantajoso.

Comment: Imagino que sim, mas por curiosidade, porque quer colocar o código (string) em um integer? Porque nao usa direto o ID do registro?

Comment: Encontrei a resposta, e coloquei a solução, tive a ajuda de um colega de trabalho.

Comment: Continuei sem entender o sentido disso, mas se conseguiu é o que importa! :)

Comment: Se mostrado o ID do registro junto com a descrição é uma exigência do cliente!

Answer (score 1):

Criei uma variável na entidade recebendo Getts e Setts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois fiz essa pequena alteração no método;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E funcionou!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]